# android.animation.Animator.mListeners leaks on Android 24 \25

Tags: android, memory-leaks, viewanimator

onDestory invokes animation stop, currently only android 24 25 will leak, other systems will not leak

The code is as follows:

```
  public static void stopAnimatorSafely(@Nullable Animator animator) {
    if (animator != null && animator.isRunning()) {
      animator.removeAllListeners();
    
      animator.end();
    }
  }
```

```
`android.os.Looper.sMainLooper     
android.os.Looper.mThread     
java.lang.Thread.threadLocals     
java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.table     
java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry[][]     
java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry.value     
android.animation.AnimationHandler.mAnimationCallbacks     
java.util.ArrayList.elementData     
java.lang.Object[][]     
android.animation.Animator.mListeners     
java.util.ArrayList.elementData     
java.lang.Object[][]     
android.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.mAnimatorSet     
android.animation.Animator.mListeners     
java.util.ArrayList.elementData     
java.lang.Object[][]   `
```